# How to show Users their Membership status so that even users without a membership status get to see the block

Tags: drupal-views, smartgroups

We have a client we would like to show the current logged in users membership status in a Drupal View alongside other contact fields. As the user may not have a membership yet at all then this can't be a CiviMember based View.

Instead we wanted to use a Smart Group in CiviCRM based on the membership status. Then in a standard CiviContact based View show details about the logged in user including the status of the smart group. But it looks like smart group data isn't available to Views. I found a few old posts about this, does anyone know if this is still the case?

Olly

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can connect your civiContact view to the membership fields without using that smart group.

I have had success (in views 3) in the past with a civiContact based view using a relationship *civiCRM Contacts: Drupal ID* and a contextual filter *User: UID* that is configured to provide a default value from the logged in user when none is available.

Then you can put in civiCRM member status field with a relationship to the logged in Drupal user with your other contact fields and filters and configure the no results behavior from there.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, [this stale issue in JIRA](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-13835) is as far as it went towards integrating Civi Smart Groups into Views.

If you are able to pick it up from there, please submit a new patch on that thread.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is still the case.