# Can Drupal Views filter contacts based on Smart Groups

Tags: drupal-views, smartgroups

Taking the liberty of creating this new ticket since the previously similarly titled (since retitled by me) [post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8642/drupal-views-and-smart-groups) was not really addressing the issue.

[Laryn](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/26/laryn-cedc-org) is correct when he said on the above post that

> From what I can tell, [this stale issue in JIRA](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-13835) is as far as it went towards integrating Civi Smart Groups into Views.

A lot of the discussion occurred in this [forum post](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=25479.15).

I am hoping a current project will help/force us to get back to this. But at this point the question is has anyone else either worked on this, or need this and could help fund us to deliver it.

Comment: another year passes and this is the latest i find (virtual loop)

Comment: we do have some code for this now but are still testing.

Comment: Just Googled and found this page again as I ran into this once more. :) Glad to hear there is some movement anyway!

Comment: hey laryn - keen to get testing/ feedback/ improvements on this if/when you can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a module in development here https://github.com/fuzionnz/civicrm_views_smartgroup

It comes in two flavours (as separate branches) — a simple and complex variety — that differ only in their implementation. For small databases, the simple version is recommended and is more robust. The complex version speeds up Views and is required for large databases with lots of group contacts, but pays a penalty in being less robust. Unfortunately, mysql's lack of materialised views makes this necessary.

Comment: For us lay folk "materialised views" means basically a cached resultset as a view.

Comment: Yes, but it also means you can create indexes against the view — otherwise the table is created on the fly without indexes.

Comment: ..and I thought it was a nice rendition of the view on a t-shirt :(   

- thanks Gents :)