# Whats the procedure to update a Group using a Smart group

Tags: civimember, groups, smartgroups, civicrm-home

I'm just wondering how can I update a group in CiviCRM using a smart group. Would it be possible to do this via a scheduled job.

Any thoughts would be highly appreciated

Comment: Could you ask your question slightly differently?  I don't think it's clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi John  What I'm trying to do is show CiviCRM group data in Drupal views however there's no clear way of doing this using a smart group. That's why I would like to update the group of contacts using the smart group

Comment: In that case, your question is actually, "How do I display smart group data in a View?"  That has a different answer.  See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish what you want.
First - since your end goal is displaying smart group data in a View, you can instead just install the `civicrm_views_smartgroup` module.  See this question: [Can Drupal Views filter contacts based on Smart Groups](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11200/can-drupal-views-filter-contacts-based-on-smart-groups)

Another way to accomplish what you're trying to do is to add members to the static group using the [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) extension and remove the smart group entirely.  If CiviRules has the correct triggers/rules to accomplish this for your use case, I recommend this approach for performance reasons.

Finally - I might be tempted to try to write some SQL that runs on a timer - either through cron or the [Scheduled SQL Tasks](https://civicrm.org/extensions/sql-tasks-extension-configurable-recurring-tasks) extension.  This is a bit risky - I'm not 100% sure how to guarantee that the smart group cache is populated at the moment your SQL runs.  This is the closest to what you're requesting, but is a risky move that could put your database in an unusable state if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think 2nd method might be the most suitable option.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I had to replace a smart group by a "normal" group was for performance reason when we started to have more than a million contacts.

Otherwise, I'd suggest to use the smart groups as you would use a normal group, and if you have performances issues, start by increasing the smart cache duration and enable the cronjob that automatically re-build them

Comment: Hi Xavier What I'm trying to do is show CiviCRM group data in Drupal views however there's no clear way of doing this using smart groups. That's why I would like to update the group of contacts using the smart group